# Binding a textbox inside a user control?

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

I have the following

**MyAwesomeControl (user control)**

It has a **text box** inside it. which is bound to a dependency property called **Text**.

**SimpleViewModel**

like object (not really a VM, but it gets the point across), sets up a collection of people (which is observable)

it also has a **SelectedPerson** property, which notifies on change

**Main page control**

Has its data context set to the **SimpleViewModel** 
contains a grid which is bound to the collection of people (this is used to select a person)

MyAwesomeControl with its **Text** property bound to SelectedPerson.Name

A TextBlock also bound to the SelectedPerson.Name

I made a small solution here : https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=82ECBE29B8DC2CD5!300

**The issue**

when i select a person in the grid the text box in MyAwesomeControl does not update.

the text block on the main form does.

how can we allow the user to supply the binding to the Text of the MyAwesomeControl, and have that update the internal text box (note this control is to be reused, so i cannot be aware of main page specific values)

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to bind to a custom dependecy property inside a custom usercontrol you need to use element binding, and don't set the `DataContext` inside your user control.

So you need to follow these steps to make your sample work:

- You need to remove the `DataContext = this;` from your userControl's constructor
- Just add a name to your UserControl e.g. `<UserControl ... x:Name="Self" >`
- And use `ElementName` with `Self` in your text binding (inside `MyAwsomeControl.xaml`):

  ```
  Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=Self, Mode=TwoWay}"
  ```

If you wan't to make the update work you also need to set `Mode` to `TwoWay` where you use your custom control (inside `MainPage.xaml`):

```
Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
```